# Setting test/train column Google AutoML

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have written some code to train a model using Google's AutoML in VertexAI. A nuance of my problem is that I need to set the test train column manually. The documentation for the method, set_test_train_column, says:

```
"""Sets the test/train (ml_use) column which designates which data
belongs to the test and train sets. This column must be categorical."""
```

My test/train column is called 'set' and consists of three values, namely, 'TEST', 'TRAIN', and 'VALIDATE'. The dtype of this column is 'object' where each cell takes a string value. I have included 'VALIDATE' as this is required when setting the test/train column when training a model in the automl section of VertexAI.

The piece of code that implements this is:

```
dataset_display_name = 'dataset_1'
table_client.set_test_train_column(dataset_display_name=dataset_display_name,
                                   column_spec_display_name='set')
```

Could someone please help me understand whether I have implemented this code correctly? Are the values in the test/train column written correctly? Does it matter that I have not used pd.Categorical to explicitly say that the test/train column is categorical? Should 'VALIDATE' be included in the test/train column?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

So this worked for me!

```
column_spec_name='split' #your split column

set_split_column = tables_client.set_test_train_column(
                dataset=dataset,
                column_spec_display_name=column_spec_name,
                column_spec_name= column_spec_name)

set_split_column
```